# AutoHotKey Loop Script Loop

Tags: autohotkey

Can someone help me with my autohotkey script? I tried looking online for loop scripts, however when i activate it, it never stops. Even when i assign an stop command. I would like to assign the stop command to F1. Thank you

```html
^!r::


WinWait, BlueStacks App Player, 
IfWinNotActive, BlueStacks App Player, , WinActivate, BlueStacks App Player, 
WinWaitActive, BlueStacks App Player, 
MouseClick, left,  335,  574
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  191,  134
MouseClick, left,  191,  134
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  191,  134
Sleep, 100
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}{ENTER}
MouseClick, left,  29,  47
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  104,  128
MouseClick, left,  104,  128
Sleep, 100
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}{ENTER}
MouseClick, left,  24,  58
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  24,  58
Sleep, 100
return
```

Comment: your code doesn't contain any loops

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
F1::Reload
```

and make sure your hotkey doesn't accidentally trigger itself by sending `^!r`.

Answer (score 0):

Your looping structure is not allowing the escape hotkey to be called.  Additionally try adding a pause:

p::Pause

If you can get your program to pause then add an exit:

Esc::ExitApp